# Mutex for multiple instances of a service

Tags: python, sql, db2

I have a program written in python which takes user input and updates a db table. Within that I have a separate function that will be executed as below:

1. Insert some values with a auto increment sequence number.
2. Get the sequence number (which has been generated last) and give it back to user.

I have multiple instances of this process in different hosts. How will I make sure that this function is executed mutually exclusive for all instances, so that the Step 2 always gives me the last generated sequence number?. Any other suggestion is also welcome.

Comment: What Db2 version/platform? How is your "auto increment sequence" implemented?

Comment: What do you mean "different hosts"?  Different databases, or different clients?  And what do you mean by "always gives me the last generated sequence number"?  For the "current" process only, or possibly should it return a value generated by another process?  What is your code **actually** doing, and what big-picture thing are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a `SEQUENCE` object and `NEXT VALUE FOR` to control the auto-increment sequence
2. Use a `FINAL TABLE` select statement to return the newly inserted values, including the auto-increment value